# How to Use GridFS Selectively?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I am new to MongoDB.

I read about how GridFS can be used to store files whose data is stored within MongoDB collections.

This feature seems to be useful for storing documents greater than 16 MB in size.

If I have a collection that has all but a few within the 16 MB range, can I selectively use GridFS for the documents that exceed the size limits?

If so, how can I do it and can I retrieve it normally along with the other documents in the collection using find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes u can use GridFS  all file sizes.

If you use any driver ex. c# driver

```
(new GridFSBucket(DataBase)).DownloadAsBytes(new ObjectId(id));
```

this method return all chunks bytes concat.

If you not use any driver get all chunks bytes;

```
db.getCollection('fs.chunks').find({files_id: ObjectId("5b75c26baf672123c8d5634a")})
```

and you must concat all bytes.